# IdentityServer 4 : how to add login logic to authorize endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm currently working on an application dealing with licences. The authentication part is handled by IdentityServer 4. 
Basically, the application can't have more than X connected users at the same time.

So my idea was to check this when the client hit the authorization endpoint, and then throw an exception if the number of maximum connections is reached.

My problem is : I don't know how to add logic in an IdentityServer endpoint... I found in the docs that IdentityServer provided events, but they are just for logging purpose... Besides that, I can't find something in the docs that can help me.

So if anyone has an idea to add some code to authorize endpoint, that would help me a lot ! Thanks !

Comment: It can depend on flow you use, but as general solution you can create some `AuthenticationController` and redirect all login request to it (it will be entry point for login requests). There you can check how many users are logged in (by checking for example saved tokens in DB). If user can proceed then just create request to identity server to get token, if no return some error code.

Comment: If you use Quickstart UI then you could easily check with the "User"-Object inside the AccountController.cs

Comment: What is your definition of logged in? And at what point is a user logged out? Please note that with IdentityServer the user does not login to _one specific application_. IdentityServer authenticates the user, even without specifying an application. Also note that with SSO it is possible to skip the login form an login automatically. And what about jwt access tokens and refresh tokens? IdentityServer is not the place for this kind of functionality. Instead add middleware to the application and use policies to authorize the user.

Comment: @RomanDoskoch The idea seems ok, but how can you do that ? In the controller, you can ask a token to IS4 on behalf of another client ?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Identity Server was here before I had to work on that licence thing... unfortunately

Comment: @FloDupuy, token is granted using for example username and password. Instead of doing request directly to identity server you can redirect it to some controller. Then check if user can log in and if can then create request to identity server and redirect response to the caller.